# Z3: str.indexof produce unexpected answer, why?

Tags: string, z3

I tried to solve the following problem with Z3:

```
(declare-const b String)
(assert (= 3 (str.indexof "abcdef" b)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

I got a result:

```
sat
(model
  (define-fun b () String 
    "de")
)
```

However, when I tried to solve the following problem with Z3:

```
(declare-const b String)
(assert (= 4 (str.indexof "abcdef" b)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

But I got the result:

```
unknown
Z3(4, 10): ERROR: model is not available
```

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

`unknown` isn't a desirable answer here, but it is not a bug either. It simply means that z3 wasn't able to construct a model to satisfy your constraints, but it also couldn't decide that they aren't unsatisfiable either. The decidability of the theory of strings is an open problem, so this is not surprising.

By the way, you must be using an old version of z3. When I use your scripts I get:

```
$ z3 smt.string_solver=z3str3 a.smt2
sat
(model
  (define-fun b () String
    "d")
)
```

and

```
$ z3 smt.string_solver=z3str3 a.smt2
sat
(model
  (define-fun b () String
    "e")
)
```

respectively. So, looks like things did indeed improve!

Note that z3 comes with several string solvers, and the command-line parameter `smt.string_solver=z3str3` picks `z3str3`, the most recent incarnation. Allowed values are:

- `z3str3`: specialized string solver
- `seq`: sequence solver
- `auto`: use static features to choose best solver

Unfortunately, there isn't a clear choice here; typically you need to try all and see which one works the best for you. (And if they disagree on `sat`/`unsat`, report that as a bug! The differences should only be in performance.)

Comment: No thanks needed! The way to show appreciation on stack-overflow is the accept the answer so others will find it useful as the correct response.